# Convert audio input to time and display it using c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, audio

I need to convert sound to time using c#, I need to extract the SMPTE time code from audio input and display the time in hh:mm:ss format.
I don't know how to get started if someone did that kind of task in the past and could help me that would be amazing.

The sound is generated from other device that is conected to the sound card of the computer and I need to absorb it and convert it to time.

here is an example of audio input: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjH0RFV206M

Comment: I'd start here: https://github.com/x42/libltc

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `MeidaPlayer` from the `System.Windows.Media` Libary. 
Open your sound file and play it:

```
MediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(@path));
MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Get the TimeSpan of your File:

```
MediaPlayer.NaturalDuration
```

and also retreive the current position with:

```
MediaPlayer.Position
```

For more info see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: if you can give me more detailed explenation of how to actually display the time from the sound input that would be great!

Comment: Do you know how to create a TextBox or a Label and change its value?

Comment: I don't know how to take the sound and understand what time every sound refer to...

Comment: the sound is generated from other device and I need to absorb it and convert it to time

Comment: if the other device does note convert the sound into a file, which you can load via it's path, this exceeds my knowledge. sorry